# How to add a description to square line item?

Tags: php, square

I'm having some trouble to add a description after the product name in Checkout API from Square.

This is how I add an item. (It works)

```
    $price = new \SquareConnect\Model\Money;
    $price->setAmount((int)str_replace(".","", $_SESSION['shippingCost']));
    $price->setCurrency('CAD');

    //Create the line item and set details
    $book = new \SquareConnect\Model\CreateOrderRequestLineItem;
    $book->setName($_SESSION['language']['shipping']." (".$_SESSION['shippingService'].")");

    //DESCRIPTION HERE

    $book->setQuantity((string) count($_SESSION['products']));
    $book->setBasePriceMoney($price);
    array_push($lineItems, $book);
```

Here is a reference of what I want to achieve.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dQpU.jpg)

Comment: I would assume the documentation for this API would be the best place to look for such a thing.

Comment: [`CreateOrderRequestLineItem`](https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/blob/master/docs/Model/CreateOrderRequestLineItem.md) appears to have a `setNote` method, that is probably what you are looking for. (Although, take note what it says on top there, _“Deprecated: Please use the OrderLineItem type in the order field of CreateOrderRequest instead.”_ - so maybe time to change your approach regarding that, if you want to write future-proof code.)

Comment: @04FS For the version I have it works perfectly with `setNote` Thank you. I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

"CreateOrderRequestLineItem appears to have a setNote method, that is probably what you are looking for. (Although, take note what it says on top there, “Deprecated: Please use the OrderLineItem type in the order field of CreateOrderRequest instead.” - so maybe time to change your approach regarding that, if you want to write future-proof code.)" – 04FS

`$book->setNote("test");` is the way to go.

Thank you @04FS